# Pulling Data Based on Split Columns - Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

Is there a way to pull in data based on columns that have been split in Spotfire? I know that you can insert a transformation > insert calculated column to make a calculated column more permanent to pull in data based on it, but not sure how to do this when columns have been split.

Comment: can you please be more specific? what do you mean by "split"?

Comment: @niko perhaps this? https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-bauthor/7.8.0/doc/html/en-US/GUID-BD220580-F0A3-4934-B2B7-F845F23F1F02.html I'm not familiar with this at all though.